# How to get ADFS to respond to a query about an user's email address

Tags: saml, adfs

I'm working in a company that uses Microsoft Active Directory. We have an external company that provides an internal web site for a particular project. The site is external to the company. The sign on to the external site is the user's company email.

We want a system whereby the external site calls into the organisation's AD to verify if an email address is still valid or if the user has left the company. It should be a simple call to Active Directory Federation Services or some sort of SAML interface. The call would be a simple request 'here's an email, is it valid?' and the response is either yes or no.

Our IT department are trying to tell us that it's too complicated and I don't believe them. I think they just don't want to do it.

Does anyone know how easy it would be to create a simple system that would allow an external service to do the query outlined above.

Answer (score 2):

ADFS is not meant to do that. However, a by-product of using it, would be the validation you are looking for.

The first question would be: what is the authentication method of your app? e-mail and what else? password? which password? Does the app keep a database of users/passwords?

ADFS works as an "identity provider" and would authenticate users in AD. ADFS would supply a security token that can be consumed by your app. Part of the information sent in the security token could very well be (and often is) the user e-mail address (that's why it is a "by-product").

For this to work, the app would have to be changed to accept security tokens (SAML tokens to be specific). If the app is .NET based, then it is done usually with WIF (WIndows Identity Foundation).

This approach would be the most elegant and secure because the app would delegate the responsibility of authenticating users to the authority of these employees: AD.

App --trusts--> ADFS --authenticates--> AD

Setting up ADFS, etc is not super-difficult, but it is not super-simple either, and might not be worth just for this app. There are other lighter weight alternatives: open source products like [Identity Server](http://thinktecture.github.io/), or [products](http://auth0.com) like the one I work on.

Now, if all you need to do is to validate that the e-mail actually exists, the best is to send a verification message to that address with some unique code that the user sends back. This is the same approach used in many common web apps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. however the company is totally paranoid about any kind of outside access. We're going to be provided with a tool that allows us to manually check if emails are valid. So we won't be using ADFS

Answer (score 0):

Agree with everything @Eugenio said - have same questions about authentication.

But if you simply want code to query an user's email address in AD, you use the [AD API's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. however the company is totally paranoid about any kind of outside access. We're going to be provided with a tool that allows us to manually check if emails are valid. So we won't be using ADFS –

Comment: You don't need to open ADFS to outside access. That is a very common misunderstanding. The app *doesn't* communicate with ADFS at all. ADFS needs to be addressable by the users (their browsers actually). It could all be inside the intranet, and the app in the internet. The only requirement is that the browser can connect to all components involved.